# 2 buttons on a mainView,bringing different views when tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 2 buttons. Each button is bringing a subview on top of the main view.
I'm checking in each button tapped method if the other button view is active then first dismiss it and then bring up its own view but for that I need to tap button twice. Does popover passthrough-view apply here as well?

Comment: what have you done as yet? some of your code would give us a better idea

Comment: I got the issue,was bringing subview when button tapped based on the title of button..Was removing the subview at other locations as well but didnt set the Title of button..Hence subview cudnt come as the comparision condition failed when button tapped(4 bringing up subview)..Thanks Anyways.